# Primeiro valor em uma função map no javascript

Tags: javascript, react, map

Eu tenho uma função **map** do JavaScript onde eu retorno todas as fotos de um certo registro. Dentre essas fotos, uma delas tem que receber um texto, que no meu caso é *Foto principal*, que sempre será o primeiro elemento do array. A dúvida é que o texto sempre vai para todas as imagens, e não faço ideia de como colocar o texto apenas na primeira foto.

Segue abaixo o código em questão.

```
<ul>
  {fotoApi?.fotos?.map((foto, index) => (
    <li key={index} style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
      <img
        style={cssListImg}
        src={fotoApi.fotos[index]}
        onClick={() => {
          setFile(fotoApi.fotos[index]);
          setImg(null);
          setI(index);
          setImgSel(foto);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      {/* fotoApi.fotos[0] ? <>Foto principal</> : <>""</> */}
      {/* A linha acima é o que eu tentei, mas sem sucesso */}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Como solicitado por @VirgilioNovic, meu "fotos" é criado da seguinte forma:

```
const [fotoApi, setFotoApi] = useState({fotos: [], caminhoimagem: ""}];
```

Comment: primeiro tem que fazer fora do `map`! e depois fazer um `slice` para pular a primeira imagem!

Comment: tem outros erros também, cade seu exemplo do objeto fotos?

Comment: Podes colocar um `if (index !== 0) return dentro desse `onClick`... mas a sugestão do @VirgilioNovic é mais correta. Pergunta: todas as imagens são clicáveis?

Comment: @Sergio, sim, todas são, e devem ser clicáveis

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou tentar o que você mandou aqui ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender, se quer imprimir a primeira item de um jeito e os outros de outra forma um exemplo de um código bem simples é:

```js
function App() {
  const [tarefas, setTarefas] = React.useState([
    {'id': 1, 'desc': 'Tarefa 1'},
    {'id': 2, 'desc': 'Tarefa 2'},
    {'id': 3, 'desc': 'Tarefa 3'},
    {'id': 4, 'desc': 'Tarefa 4'},
    {'id': 5, 'desc': 'Tarefa 5'},
  ]);
  return (
    <ul>
      {tarefas.length && (<li key={tarefas[0].id}>{tarefas[0].desc}</li>)}
      {tarefas.slice(1).map((t, i) => <li key={i}>{t.id}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

onde essa linha:

```
{tarefas.length && (<li key={tarefas[0].id}>{tarefas[0].desc}</li>)}
```

pega a primeira poisção do `array` e a próxima:

```
{tarefas.slice(1).map((t, i) => <li key={i}>{t.id}</li>)}
```

com `slice` e `map` pega o restante, acredito ser essa a sua duvida!

```
{tarefas.slice(1).map((t, i) => <li key={i}>{t.id}</li>)}
```

a documentação [slice](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_slice.htm#:%7E:text=%20JavaScript%20String%20-%20slice%20%28%29%20Method%20,Example.%20Try%20the%20following%20example.%20%20More%20).